# .htaccess URL-Rewrite solution?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I need to rewrite my url using .htaccess

The url is

```
http://www.domain.com/subfolder/search-brands/index.php/?q=Garment Bags&brand=traveler apos s choice
```

And i want it to work like this

```
http://www.domain.com/subfolder/search-brands/Garment Bags/traveler apos s choice
```

Anyone can make it? Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: Where you put htacces - in root or in `/subfolder`?

Comment: in the subfolder - search-brands

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this code in your `/subfolder/search-brands/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /subfolder/search-brands/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ index.php?q=$1&brand=$2 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: i think i've haven't asked properly but sometimes keyword,brand name can contain uppercase characters and spaces like this


"http://www.domain.com/subfolder/search-brands/index.php/?q=Garment Bags&brand=traveler apos s choice"